# Multiple basic app gateway listeners using wrong SSL cert

Tags: azure, ssl, dns, ssl-certificate, azure-application-gateway

I have 3 different wildcards domains setup on an app gateway (tier 2) all using a basic listener. So for instance. I have *.example1.com, *.example2.com, and *.example3.com all as basic listeners on app gateway all using SSL and setup with 3 different wildcard certs.

However, if I make a request to either foobar.example2.com or foobar.example3.com in a browser I get a cert mismatch error message indicating that the cert being uses is example1.com.

Is there a misconfiguration I might have somewhere or is this a limitation of azure app gateway?

[image]

[image]

Comment: How do you test? Is your client using SNI?

Comment: This is not in GA i guess and you need to upgrade your App Gateway to Standard v2.